# Question 11 and 12 from Hartshorne chapter 2 section 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

the questions are :
[image]

this is my attempt :
As we know a presheaf is a sheaf if it satisfies the folowing equalizer diagram:
$$\mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \prod_{i} \mathcal{F}(U_i) {{{} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {}}} \prod_{i, j} \mathcal{F}(U_i \cap U_j)$$
when the $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover .As we know inverse limit commutes with product and is an exact functor that is preserves equalizer  (in a same directed system) So 12 is clear. for 11 it is a little bit less obvious since direct limit do not always commutes with infinite products but since X is Noetherian we can assume that the product is finite and as we know direct limit preserve finite products.

I Dont know if my answer is correct.
i would be grateful if someone could give me some correction \approval .
thanks you in advance !!

Comment: Yeah this sounds correct, although it might be better to say that inverse limits commute with products and equalizers (and the direct limits commute with finite products and equalizers).

Comment: I added your advice thank!